# How can I go about using Hasura CLI to export metadata via Windows Active Directory Login?

Tags: metadata, hasura, hasura-cli

Here is information about our technical environment:

- Hasura GraphQL Current server version: v2.6.2-pro.1
- Hasura CLI version 2.15.0
- We log onto the Hasura GraphQL Web UI Console using our Windows Active Directory Login (essentially Single-SignOn SSO) (therefore,
  we do not have an admin secret)

However, the official Hasura GraphQL Technical Tutorial Guide only gives examples showing the admin secret being supplied in the Hasura CLI command line console arguments (https://hasura.io/docs/latest/migrations-metadata-seeds/migrations-metadata-setup/)

`hasura init demo-project --endpoint https://docs-demo.hasura.app --admin-secret mySecret`

How can I go about using Hasura CLI to export metadata via Windows Active Directory Login? (I would be interested in Hasura CLI command line examples).

Answer (score 1):

as of now you’ll have to set an admin secret via environment variables and use that via the CLI. Please file a feature request via Github if you need this so we can get it tracked and prioritized.

Comment: However, our DevOps Platform team has configured our Hasura GraphQL Web UI Console in such a way that Only Windows Active Directory Login (essentially Single-SignOn SSO) works ( i.e, No --admin-secret )

Comment: You would set the admin secret via the `HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET` environment variable on Hasura. As of now you'd need an admin secret to do the CLI command. You can also export the metadata via the Console but thats not the same as the init command https://hasura.io/docs/latest/migrations-metadata-seeds/manage-metadata/#export-metadata

Comment: However, in order to execute "hasura metadata export" , Would I need to some how provide some sort of login credentials so that we can log on to our Hasura GraphQL Server ( via the endpoint url )? ( Essentially, providing some kind of Windows Active Directory Login credentials. )  How would I do that?

Comment: You can use the console to export and import metadata, this link has a console tab you can click https://hasura.io/docs/latest/migrations-metadata-seeds/manage-metadata/#export-metadata

Comment: @crazyTech I've been told we have something called personal access tokens https://hasura.io/docs/latest/api-reference/cloud-api-reference/#authentication that you can use to login to the pro console, it may be be able to allow exporting metadata as well https://hasura.io/docs/latest/hasura-cli/hasurapro-cli/#authentication-with-the-hasura-pro-cli